# Beanshell Preprocessor in jmeter getting an error

Tags: jmeter

For encrypting the input I am using the below code but facing the error
import java.util.Base64;

```
String plainPassword=vars.get("PW");
log.info(plainPassword);
String encodedPassword = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainPassword.getBytes()));
vars.put("encodedpassword", encodedPassword);
log.info("encodedpassword");
ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(encryptedpassword);
```

Error says:

```
Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: import java.util.Base64;
String plainPassword=vars.get("PW");
log.info(plainPa . . . : Typed variable dec
```

Comment: Tried with Removing import java.util.Base64; Even though facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. I fail to see encodeBase64() function in [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) JavaDoc so double check the source from which you copied and pasted it.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you can change 2nd line of your "script" to something like:

   ```
   String encodedPassword = plainPassword.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
   ```

   Full correct code just in case:

   ```
   String plainPassword=vars.get("PW");
   log.info(plainPassword);
   String encodedPassword = plainPassword.bytes.encodeBase64().toString();
   vars.put("encodedpassword", encodedPassword);
   log.info(encodedPassword);
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', encodedPassword, '');
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)